# What is the non-deprecated replacement for @scr.property nameRef?

Tags: java, annotations, javadoc, apache-felix

I am replacing some deprecated Javadoc annotation in code I am unfamiliar with.  Most javadoc annotations easily translate to org.apache.felix.scr.annotations, but I'm not sure how to translate this one:

```
/**
 * @scr.property
 *   nameRef="org.apache.sling.auth.core.spi.AuthenticationHandler.PATH_PROPERTY"
 *   values.0="/"
*/
```

What [@Property annotation](http://felix.apache.org/site/scr-annotations.html#SCRAnnotations-Property) does the above translate to--particularly the nameRef portion?

```
@Property( ???)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a guess...simple enough once it dawned on me that the Javadoc syntax was saying the name referred to some enum value.  Guess I was having a momentary lapse of reason:

```
@Property(
     name = org.apache.sling.auth.core.spi.AuthenticationHandler.PATH_PROPERTY,
     value = "/"
)
```

Similar for valueRef, which I encountered in another item.